# C3 Tick marks not lining up with data after API Load call

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

This code is for a chart we are displaying in users profiles. It is a graph displaying their statistics for certain date ranges (weekly, monthly, yearly, lifetime). Whatever range we make the default, the tick marks are lined up perfectly with the data points. Whenever they choose a different interval, the ticks no longer line up.

Initial generation of chart:

```
this.chartSpline = C3.generate({
            bindto: '.splineChart',
            colors:'#1BA39C',
            data: {
                xFormat: '%m-%d-%Y',
                columns: [this.columns, this.rows],
                type: 'area-spline',
                x: 'Date',
            },
            padding: {
                right: 100,
                left: 100,
            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    type : 'timeseries',
                    tick:{
                        fit: true,
                        count: this.rows.length/2,
                        format: '%m/%d',
                    },
                    padding:{
                        left:0,
                        right: 10
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    padding:{
                        top:50,
                        bottom: 0
                    },
                    label: {
                        text: 'Minutes played',
                                position: 'outer-middle'
                    }
                }
            },
            point: {
                r: 8,
            },
            legend: {
                show: false
            }
        });
```

The above code is in one backbone view, then we load another backbone view which has the load function. The load function gets called when the user selects a new date range:

```
this.plot.load({columns: [columns, rows]});
```

Any help you can provide me would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of this snippet of code:

```
count: this.rows.length/2,
```

and it works fine now